# Active Record get parent records based on child data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have several related models: `Category` `has_many` `Question`. `Question` `has_many` `Answer`. I need:

1. Get all Categories, where at least one `Question` has `Answer`
2. Count all Questions, that has at least one `Answer`(how many Questions inside `Category` has Answers)
3. Get all Categories, where all Questions has 0 Answers
4. Count all Questions, that has not Answers ( How many Questions inside `Category`, that has not Answers).

EDIT

If I want get list of categories with answers and list of categories without answers?

```
cats = []
@categories_with_answers = Category.all.each do |cat|
  cats << cat if cat.questions.joins(:answers).count > 0
end
```

How I can write this snippet in more cleaner way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `includes` and `joins` to query relationships:

1. `Category.joins(questions: :answers)`
2. `Question.joins(:answers).count`
3. `Category.includes(questions: :answers).where(questions: { answers: { question_id: nil }})`
4. `Question.includes(:answers).where(answers: { question_id: nil })`

There's a good blog article that discusses these approaches in more detail here: https://www.pagerduty.com/blog/sql-left-join-trick/.

**EDIT**

For an individual category, the query is similar:

```
@category = Category.find(params[:category_id])

@category.questions.joins(:answers).count
```

This would be equivalent to:

```
Question.joins(:answers).where(questions: { category_id: @category.id }).count
```

The same principle applies to `includes`...

```
@category.questions.includes(:answers).where(answers: { question_id: nil })
```

Comment: Thanks for help, how I can get results of 2 and 4 per category? I need count questions with at leas one Answer for each of my Category. And, also, I need count all questions without Answer for each of my Category.